# The chosen one is destined to defeat the devil

Tags: biology, creature-design, xenobiology, alternate-worlds, alternate-reality

Legend says the chosen one will be able to defeat the devil without fighting it. Over the years many brave adventurers have tried and miserably failed taking down the devil with various plans and traps
[image]

<sup>Copyright [Alex Konstad](http://www.alexkonstad.com/)</sup>

All the adventures before were deemed as unworthy and eaten by the devil which is a symbiotic creature awaiting for a host.

But a rather lucky individual was fortunate to be considered perfect for the symbiosis and instead of being killed she became the host for the devil which now being part of her body is able to reproduce and make new devils.

Apparently the only reason no other adventurer was able to dominate the devil was because they were all male.
For plot reasons the symbiote also makes her incredibly more powerful and invulnerable, but this is not really strictly important for the question.

My question is if there are any animals who can live by themselves but need a permanent fusion with a host in order to reproduce but without killing the host.

Comment: Need a host to reproduce? Yes,there are many, from uni to multicellular creatures. Fusing with the host? Unless you count what cordyceps does to ants or what some viruses do when inserting their genetic material into ours, such a creature doesn't exist as far as I'm aware of (the closest from fusing to a host which I know are a species of tardigrade which will kill and eat a fish's tongue and then take its place inside the fish's mouth, essentially becoming a new tongue and the anglerfish male fusing to the female to become a pair of gonads, but that doesn't give the female superstrengh).

Comment: Here's some inspiration: https://www.statnews.com/2016/04/15/parasite-benefits-humans/

Comment: i dont get the connection between the title and the question.....also if she was destined to defeat the devil why she give birth to new devils? or iam mistaken and she is not the chosen one? originally i though the girl has disease or something that make her has short lifespan to  end the devil together after fusing.

Comment: I've done it this time, but in future, if you could remember to add image accreditation, that would fit with stackexchange's legal obligations.

Comment: this question needs some serious revision. I'll leave it for now, but you really need to make it about the question (MAYBE one line) and not the story (which is only tenuous to the question at best).

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Male (deep sea) angler fish fuse permanently to the female by biting her and melding into her body. The bloodstreams join and most of his organs atrophy except for the gonads which enlarge. This is the only way they can reproduce

Comment: This is one of those answers that's so good I'm not even going to try to write another answer.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza FEEL MY POWER